# Mockito Page<> test return null

Tags: spring, mockito, stub

I'm testing controller using mockito. Even though I stubbed about the getBoardList, It doesn't initiate the method.

This is the controller. getBoardList() doesn't initiate when I checked in debug mode.

```
@GetMapping
public String getBoardListView(@Valid @Nullable BoardDto.Request request,
                               @PageableDefault(size = 10, sort = "createdAt", direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) Pageable pageable,
                               ModelMap map) {
    Page<BoardDto.Response> boardList = postService.getBoardList(request, pageable);

    map.addAttribute("boardList", boardList);
    return "board/index";
}
```

This is the controllerTest

```
@MockBean private PostService postService;

@Test
void getBoardListView() throws Exception {

    Page<BoardDto.Response> mock = Mockito.mock(Page.class);
    when(postService.getBoardList(eq(null), any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(mock);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/board").with(csrf()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("boardList"))
            .andExpect(view().name("board/index"));

    then(postService).should().getBoardList(any(BoardDto.Request.class), any(Pageable.class));
}
```

This is PostService interface.

```
public interface PostService {

    Page<BoardDto.Response> getBoardList(BoardDto.Request request, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This is PostServiceImpl

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<BoardDto.Response> getBoardList(BoardDto.Request request, Pageable pageable) {
        return postRepository.findBoardList(request, pageable).map(BoardDto.Response::from);
    }
```

}

Comment: Consider annotations for creating mock objects.  Also, consider doReturn().when() instead of when().thenReturn.

Comment: How do you wire your `postService` mock into your service? Where do you create it? Please show a full [mre].

Comment: @knittl I added more info !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
when(postService.getBoardList(eq(null) ...
```

try:

```
when(postService.getBoardList(any(BoardDto.Request.class)
```

Comment: There is one thing i can't understand. Why it doesn't work with eq(null) ? I checked it in debug mode and it works same (it has same request instance).

Comment: I assumed that you were not calling the getBoardListView method with a null value (i.e. had an instantiated object as the BoardDto.Request parameter value).  If that was the case then `eq(null)` would never match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a null argument, use [`ArgumentMatchers#isNull`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.1.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isNull()), not `eq(null)`:

```
when(postService.getBoardList(isNull(), any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(mock);
```